# How to declare a static date when executing a stored proc script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to execute a script via Management Studio.

Something like this:

```
USE [MYDB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[myTABLE]
        @AsAt = Datetime('27/01/2012 10:37:31'),
        @BatchID = 6754848

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Keep getting errors saying it can't convert from nVarChar to date time. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You have a stored procedure called `[dbo].[myTABLE]`? There is no `Datetime` function that casts strings to datetime. Just use a string in an unambiguous format.

Answer (score 2):

If this is for SQL Server you should use `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm`. It will be safe regardless of locale settings.

**Note:** The `T` is important and should be in the string `2012-01-27T10:37:31`.
Another option would be to remove `-` `20120127 10:37:31`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify custom DateTime style and what is most important - you can not use date time functions is SP call directly so cache converted datetime value in the temporary variable
thanks to [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) for this point:

```
DECLARE @return_value int  
DECLARE @tmpDate varchar(20)
SELECT @tmpDate = CONVERT(datetime, '27/01/2012 10:37:31', 103)

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[myTABLE]         
        @AsAt = @tmpDate,
        @BatchID = 6754848
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

> Syntax for CONVERT:
>
> CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )

Answer (score 0):

Normally when using strings as dates you do:

```
DECLARE @mydate AS DATETIME

SELECT @mydate = CAST('2012-01-27 10:37:31' AS DATETIME)

SELECT @mydate


-----------------------
2012-01-27 10:37:31.000
```

Try using CAST() or CONVERT() check the T-SQL help on those 2.

NOTE: use the format mentioned by Mikael (i.e.'2012-01-27 10:37:31.000')
Or you will probably see errors like this:

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 5
The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
```

IT is true what was said about convert/cast not working on a procedure call so you need to change a little bit your query:

```
DECLARE @return_value int
DECLARE @AsAt DATETIME 
SELECT @AsAt = CAST('2012-01-27 10:37:31' AS DATETIME)
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[myTABLE] 
        @AsAt,
        @BatchID = 6754848 

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Comment: The `T` is important and should be in the date string. Without the `T` it can fail if you have for instance `set language german`. Have a look [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/wishlist.html#YYYYMMDD) for more info.